# Capture template without body

Tags: org-mode, org-capture, template

I have an org-formatted file named `foo.org` that consists only of headings (without
body).  Notice the absence of blank lines.

```
* one
** a
** b
* two
** c
* three
```

I want to use capture templates to add a sub-headings (without body) under
the top-level headings `one` or `two` while preserving the original format.
To do this I have these templates

```
(setq org-capture-templates
  (list
    '("f" "Foo")
    '("fo" "One" entry
       (file+headline "/tmp/foo.org" "one")
       "** TODO %?"
       :prepend t :unnarrowed t :jump-to-captured t)
    '("ft" "Two" entry
       (file+headline "/tmp/foo.org" "two")
       "** TODO %?"
       :prepend t :unnarrowed t :jump-to-captured t)))
```

The problem is the templates automatically include a blank line after the
heading

```
**␣TODO␣
```

which I have to delete manually every time.  Is it possible to tell Emacs not to insert
a newline character after the heading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `:empty-lines 0` to each template's set of properties. Zero is in fact the default value, so it would be strange if this was the solution, but maybe worth a try.